# How can i select a Resources from MergedDictionaries

Tags: wpf, resources

To begin i read all resources from xml in my MergedDictionaries
and now I like "select" any Resources as Current.Resources

PSEUDOCODE:

```
Application.Current.Resources = Resources.From.MergedDictionaries.Selected(themeId.Path);
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.FindResource`, it also searches MergedDictionaries

Comment: thx, but this solves not my problem.. i have 3 complete styles in my MergedDictionaries , the last Resources of them will be loaded. And now can I select other complete Style from ListBox and this like a select from MergedDictionaries. With FindResource can i change only the element or?

Comment: You can access a specific merged dictionary with Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[i], then access the resource from the dictionary using the indexer (dict[key])